# Conversational Analytics using Power BI & Cortana

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, cortana, cortana-intelligence, cortana-skills-kit

We want to develop Cortana skills such that when asked a question it queries the dataset in Power BI and returns an answer in speech. For example, the user asks Cortana, "Which customer had the highest default rate last week?" Cortana queries the dataset in Power BI and answers, "John Doe". How can we use Cortana skills and Power BI to build a solution which satisfies this requirement? or any ideas maybe using Azure Bot Services, Application insights... with Cortana?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would be a cool example! And it is definitely do-able. There is no current example
[on bot service samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples).

There are a couple ways you could approach it.  You could use Power BI app deep links, where the Cortana skill maps speech to a known dashboard or report, or you could build a model that ties right in to Power BI data.

For the latter, you'd need to create a bot and add the Cortana channel. Inside your bot, you'd need to get an access token and pass it off to Power BI's REST API to get whatever you need.  I believe you could use Cortana's Connected Services to do this. Check out [connected services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/authentication), [how Graph oauth works](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-overview) and [getting access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/get-azuread-access-token).  Then check out [using Power BI for develoers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/getreport) to see what API to use (get dashboard, report, dataset, etc.) You'd rip whatever result you're looking for and add it as the *speak* property on the message you send back to the user.

For the former, you wouldn't get a speech result, but you could drill down into the report. Check out Power BI apps's [deep linking capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/mobile/mobile-apps-deep-link-specific-location) and how to [deep link from Cortana](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/launch-apps-from-skills).